# SQL Querying on tuple values

Tags: sql, nested, tuples, where-clause

I need to write a write a SQL query that selects values from a table based on several tuples of selection criteria. It could be done using a where clause like this :

```
where (a = 1 and  b='a') or (a=5 and b='s')
```

Is the best way to select:

```
select a, pk from x where a in (1,5)
select b, pk from x where b in ('a','s')
```

and join the result of the two queries using the primary key?

Comment: review your question, I think it's a little unclear what you want

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? MSSQL server, Oracle....?

Comment: I I were you I would use the first solution you mentioned. So there is no need for a join

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something(`a self join`) like this:

```
select x.a, x.pk 
from x 
join x x2 on x.pk=x2.pk
where x.a in (1,5)
      and x2.b in ('a','s')
```

?

Comment: Yes that was my thought also, but how does this query perform compared to using and/or in a while clause? The other thing is, what if I am looking for numerical values greater than x? I want values that satisfy a bigger than x and b equeal to 'a'. I don't want values of a where b has the value 's' or any other value for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join on table expression from `VALUES`. You can add in `VALUES` as much rows as you want. It will work on `MSSQL`:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE ( a INT, b CHAR(1) )

INSERT  INTO @x
VALUES  ( 1, 'a' ),
        ( 1, 'b' ),
        ( 1, 'c' ),
        ( 2, 'd' ),
        ( 2, 'e' ),
        ( 5, 'f' ),
        ( 5, 's' )


SELECT  x.*
FROM    @x x
        JOIN ( 
               VALUES ( 1, 'a'), 
                      ( 5, 's') 
             ) AS v( a, b ) ON x.a = v.a AND x.b = v.b
```

Output:

```
a   b
1   a
5   s
```

Comment: I like this solution, however I am looking for a solution that will work with any database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you want write a SQL that uses a combination of two filters. Here is a simple solution that will work in any database.
Create a new column say "COLUMN_NEW" in the same table or build a temp table or a view with a new column (plus existing columns from original table).
Insert concatenated values of column a and column b in "COLUMN_NEW". Based on the example mentioned by you values in "COLUMN_NEW" will be "1a" and "5s"
Now you may have a different syntax for concat in different databases. Example concat(a,b) in SQL server.
SQL to select records from the table will be `select * from table where COLUMN_NEW in ("1a",5s");`